# Element type is invalid: expected a stringor a class/function but got: object.

Tags: ios, react-native, navigator-ios

I'm having some trouble working with the NavigatorIOS in react native.
If I put my component in the initial route it works just fine but if I try to reach it from another component it gives me this error:

**Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. check the render method of 'NavigatorIOS'.**

here is the code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  NavigatorIOS,
  FadeInView,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Menu from './Menu.ios';


class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.onForward = this.onForward.bind(this);
  }

  onForward(Menu){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: Menu,
      title: 'Menu',
      navigationBarHidden: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.img}
          source={require('./img/scrittaNera.png')}
          onLoadStart={(e) => this.setState({loading: true})}
          />
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onForward.bind(this)}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get Inspired</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove Menu from 
`onForward(Menu) {`.

The parameter Menu shadows the component imported with `import Menu from './Menu.ios';`.